# AS3: Sort Two Fields

Tags: sorting, actionscript-3

PLEASE NEED HELP
This is what I'm doing:

```
var my_array_W:Array = new Array();
my_array_W.push({cor:Acorrect, tem:AnewTime, tab: "TB_A", nom:Aoseasnnombre});
my_array_W.push({cor:Bcorrect, tem:BnewTime, tab: "TB_B", nom:Boseasnnombre});
my_array_W.push({cor:Ccorrect, tem:CnewTime, tab: "TB_C", nom:Coseasnnombre}); 
my_array_W.push({cor:Dcorrect, tem:DnewTime, tab: "TB_D", nom:Doseasnnombre});
my_array_W.push({cor:Ecorrect, tem:EnewTime, tab: "TB_E", nom:Eoseasnnombre});
my_array_W.push({cor:Fcorrect, tem:FnewTime, tab: "TB_F", nom:Foseasnnombre});
```

This Output:

```
[tab] |  [cor]  |        [tem]
 TB_A      3          8.6877651541
 TB_B      4         12.9287651344
 TB_C      1       6199.334999999999923
 TB_D      4         33.6526718521
 TB_E      4         31.90468496844
 TB_F      1          6.334999999923
```

So then I sort:

```
my_array_W.sortOn("tem", Array.NUMERIC);
my_array_W.sortOn("cor", Array.NUMERIC | Array.DESCENDING);
```

And Geting this T_T :

```
[tab] |  [cor]  |        [tem]
 TB_E      4         31.90468496844
 TB_D      4         33.6526718521
 TB_B      4         12.9287651344
 TB_A      3          8.6877651541
 TB_F      1         31.90468496844
 TB_C      1       6199.334999999999923
```

I just wanna sort a Winner Table by Time(the less) and Correct(the high)

So the Winner is the One who make more correct answers in less time.

I really try so hard to get a sort like this:

```
[tab] |  [cor]  |        [tem]
 TB_B      4         12.9287651344
 TB_E      4         31.90468496844
 TB_D      4         33.6526718521
 TB_A      3          8.6877651541
 TB_F      1          6.334999999923
 TB_C      1       6199.334999999999923
```

But couldn't achieve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Organis was so close.

But Finally I do the trick :D
With this line

```
my_array_W.sortOn(['cor', 'tem'],[ Array.NUMERIC | Array.DESCENDING, Array.NUMERIC ]);
```

I get the result I was looking for
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that you sort it 2 times. The second time does not additionally sort the sorted, it just sorts the whole **Array** anew. What you need is to use the **[Array.sort(...)](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sort())** method with a **compareFunction** argument:

```
my_array_W.sort(sortItems);

// Should return -1 if A < B, 0 if A == B, or 1 if A > B.
function sortItems(A:Object, B:Object):Number
{
    // First, the main criteria.
    if (A.cor > B.cor) return -1;
    if (A.cor < B.cor) return 1;

    // If A.cor == B.cor, then secondary criteria.
    if (A.tem < B.tem) return -1;
    if (A.tem > B.tem) return 1;

    // Items seem to be equal.
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your case you have to write a costume sorter function. to do that check my example:

Your first data:

```
var arr:Array = [];
arr.push({cor:4,tem:13});
arr.push({cor:3,tem:12});
arr.push({cor:2,tem:1});
arr.push({cor:3,tem:16});
arr.push({cor:1,tem:11});
```

The sorting function and sort result for sample one based on tem:
    arr.sort(scrollSorter);

```
function temSorter(a,b):int
{
    if(a.tem<b.tem)
        return 1 ;//To pass a forward
    else(a.tem>b.tem)
        return -1;//To pass a backward
    return 0;//a and b are same. 
}
```

And the result is:

```
  The result is this:
    [
     {
      "cor": 3,
      "tem": 16
     },
     {
      "cor": 4,
      "tem": 13
     },
     {
      "cor": 3,
      "tem": 12
     },
     {
      "cor": 1,
      "tem": 11
     },
     {
      "cor": 2,
      "tem": 1
     }
    ]
```

Now the sample based on something close you need:
arr.sort(scrollSorter);

```
function userScoreCalculator(a):Number
        {
            return a.cor/a.tem;
        }


function winnerSorter(a,b):int
{


    var aScore:Number = userScoreCalculator(a);
    var bScore:Number = userScoreCalculator(b);
    if(aScore<bScore)
        return 1 ;
    else(aScore>bScore)
        return -1
    return 0
}
```

And the result is:

```
[
 {
  "cor": 2,
  "tem": 1
 },
 {
  "cor": 4,
  "tem": 13
 },
 {
  "cor": 3,
  "tem": 12
 },
 {
  "cor": 3,
  "tem": 16
 },
 {
  "cor": 1,
  "tem": 11
 }
]
```

Than means the person with score of 2 is winner because he made it in only 1 second. but other players are close to gather in tem parameter, so the next winner is the person with highest score. it comes from the userScoreCalculator() output. the higher output of that function is the winner.

Now take your time and change the userScoreCalculator() function to show the winner.

https://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fa4.html

Comment: Teaching nested functions is not a good idea. And `userScoreCalculator` makes no sense, since 2/1 == 4/2 etc.